# What changes to be done in ArrayList to make it behave like a Set

Tags: java

What changes to be done in ArrayList to make it behave like a Set (means it should not accept any duplicate values).

Comment: Is this homework? Otherwise I can't think of any reason why you want to do that.

Comment: in addition to @Jules very accurate remark, I'd like to add that there's a specific reason why there are different kinds of collections. If you haven't already done so, I strongly recommend you to go through the official collections tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: Just to make myself clear. I don't mind this being homework or, even better, "self-issued homework". It could be fun to implement your own idea of a Set collection type. But I don't see why you want to do that using another type of higher order collection. If it's out of curiosity, you shouldn't base the set implementation on an ArrayList. Why not extend the AbstractSet class and start doing it by yourself. @templatetypedef's remarks should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this.  Here are a two:

1. Store the elements of the `ArrayList` in random order.  When inserting a new value, do a linear scan over the elements and see if the element you're adding already exists.  If so, don't add it.  Otherwise, append it to the elements.
2. Enforce that the elements of the `ArrayList` always be stored in sorted order.  To insert a new element, do a binary search to find where that element should be placed, and if the element already exists don't insert it.  Otherwise, insert it at the given position.

However, you shouldn't be doing this.  These approaches are very slow compared to `HashSet` or `TreeSet`, which are specialized data structures optimized to handle this efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

- Create your own implementation , implement `java.util.List`
- override `add()`, `addAll()` , make use of `contains()`

Comment: wouldn't it be less work/easier to inherit from  `java.util.ArrayList` instead of `List`

Comment: @dnl yeah it would be  @Damodar  note this

Comment: If you want something to behave like a Set, don't implement `List`, implement `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, it's unclear why you need this.
Maybe LinkedHashSet is what you need?
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Other than already said, you could have a look at `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet`. If you leave the "CopyOnWrite" part away, you have your `ArraySet`.